# Adding a "Forum" to an existing Experience Cloud site

Tags: experience-cloud

We've got an existing Experience Cloud site for handling support. So customers log in to create and manage their cases.

There is a forum feature for Experience Cloud, but my understanding of it is that it's a separate new site. If that's the only way of working with it, is there perhaps a way to use links/buttons to jump to that site from the main support site?

(Although the optimal way would be to integrate all the forum features as a tab to our existing experience site)

Thanks!

Comment: You can embed collaboration features (known as Chatter) into your existing site: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_chatter.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking into it now! Looks like we make use of navigation topics within the menu bar. Doesn't seem very configurable though and I'd love a landing page for the Topics tab and there show active threads. (There is featured threads as a standard component though, but it has to be on another page)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use links or buttons to jump to the forum site from the main support site. You can include a prominent link or button on the main support site that directs users to the forum site. This way, users can easily access the forum without having to navigate through multiple pages.

As for integrating the forum features as a tab on your existing Experience Cloud site, it would depend on the specific platform and tools you are using. It is possible that there may be plugins or add-ons available to facilitate integration. I would recommend consulting the documentation and support [resources](https://www.interviewbit.com/salesforce-interview-questions/) for your platform or reaching out to their customer support for guidance on how to achieve this integration.